# Make an exact copy of my current Windows 7 partition bootable on another HDD?

Tags: windows-7, backup, boot, partitioning, restore

I have 2 HDDs:

- Drive A = 80GB SSD with my Windows 7 x64 and a 100MB System Partition that Windows made. Both NTFS.
- Drive B = 1TB HDD with a NTFS data partition.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Downloaded EASUS Partition Master Home Edition
- Made a new 80GB (81920MB) Partition on drive B
- Told it make an exact copy my Windows 7 partition on drive A on drive B's new 80GB partition.
- Made the new partition on drive B a "Primary" and "Active".
- If I take out the SSD (drive A) and leave just drive B it won't boot, I just get a black screen with a white underscore ):

Some other details:

- If possible, I don't want to format drive B or re-install windows on drive B.
- If possible, I don't want to boot from the Windows 7 DVD. My DVD Reader/Writer is broken and my pendrive is just 2GB. But, I can borrow an external DVD Reader or something if it's necessary.
- No encryption is being used.
- I can download other software (even not-free (as in beer) software) and try to do it another way. Any links to guides, tutorials, etc. are VERY welcomed.

Pictures:

- EASUS:

  [image]
- Windows Disk Managment:

  [image]

Comment: Most of the time you will need to do a startup repair before trying to boot the new drive after you image W7 onto it....http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-easily-repair-windows-7-boot-problems-using-startup-repair/

Comment: Moab and The Journeyman geek are correct.  Usually, even if all your partition manipulations worked correctly, you still need to use start up repair to fix the MBR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific combination makes it a LITTLE tricky - you need to do two things 
1) make a image of the current install partition, to a specific partition of your 2 tb disk - most backup software can do this - almost any backup software can do this - i'd suggest something that runs on windows such as macrium reflect free or driveimage xml. A backup method with a restore disk is probably essential for the next bit.

2) ensure the boot sector is installed - many restore disks, including the windows 7 disk do this - however most of these need a cd or some other media. The easiest way is to pop out the smaller disk, run windows 7 or a restore disk (macrium does this) and get it to fix it

you seem to have part 1 squared off.

In short - for part two  the easiest way involves a cd or [USB](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2432-usb-windows-7-installation-key-drive-create.html)